# Ionic reusing the same page but different parameters

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I currently have this page on ionic that I want to reuse through router navigate based on parameters but I can't find a way currently.

Does anyone have an approach to it where it will also stack up the navigation history?

Below are my html and ts code

```
<ion-header>
        <ion-toolbar>
            <ion-title class="avenir-avenir">Help</ion-title>
            <ion-buttons slot="start">
               <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
            </ion-buttons>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

    <div class="item" (click)="go(1)">
        <label >
            <p>
                Issues
            </p>
            <ion-icon name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="item" (click)="go(2)">
        <label>
            <p>
                Account
            </p>
            <ion-icon name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="item" (click)="go(3)">
        <label>
            <p>
                Guide
            </p>
            <ion-icon name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="item" (click)="go(4)">
        <label>
            <p>
                Signing Up
            </p>
            <ion-icon name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="item" (click)="go(5)">
        <label>
            <p>
                More
            </p>
            <ion-icon name="arrow-forward"></ion-icon>
        </label>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationExtras } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-help',
    templateUrl: './help.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['./help.page.scss'],
})
export class HelpPage implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    ionViewDidLeave() { 
        console.log("123");
    }

    ionViewDidEnter() { 
        console.log("123123123123123");
    }

    ionViewWillEnter() { 
        console.log("12333333333333333");
    }

    go(page) {

        let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
            queryParams: {
              page: page
            }
        };

       this.router.navigate(['help'], navigationExtras);
    }
}
```

When I click on the next pages it stack up right now but it doesn't show any animation through my navigate and it doesn't go through my log prints except the first time.

Comment: so based on your code above in all your cases you are essentially going to the same router destination (/help) attempting to pass different params (navigation extras). So what is it that you want to achieve? what errors you see?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko I want to be able to reuse the same page (/help) based on what I have when I click on go. 

Ideally, it will stack on top of the next page (/help with a parameter) then do something with it (like calling an API if there's a value in the queryparams) then using it to display certain data. if i go back with ion-back-button, it will go back to /help from /help?page=2 for example